# Add to favourite

Tags: android, database

I'm working on  book app, when the user clicks on a book on the list, my app gives the option to add that book to favorites.so the user can view the favorite books 
but I don't know how to implement that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. I see two open questions here:

1. How to catch the user click and process the event?
2. How and where to store the book name/details?

For 1: 
Just have your activity listing the books implement the corresponding event listener. See here: [Android Doc - Input Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

For 2: 
Depends on the amount of data you want to store if it is just a list of favorite book names Preferences might do. If you want to kep the option to extend the stored list with details fo each book then a SQLite database is your choice.

There is an Android Tutorial on how to persist data as well:
See here: [Android Doc - Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

And here we have a tutorial "[Creating and using databases in Android](http://android10.org/index.php/articlesdatastorage/235-creating-and-using-databases-in-android-one)".

Comment: Hi Ali, if the answers helped then please vote them and mark one as answer. This is part of the way this platform works ;-). Thank you. Cheers

Comment: I added one more link in my answer to a database tutorial.Please see above n my answer at the end.

Comment: thanks man... exactly what I was looking for. appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a database for all the favourtes book. When ever user clicks on any just add that item in database and whenever requires to view the book just retrive it from the database and show it to the user so that the will be as you required.

Comment: depending on nos of books shared prefs is also an option,

Comment: either maintain an other table for nos oof books shared or main a bool variable in first table and if it is true then the book is shared else not shared

Comment: i meant sharedprefs ...and this is not my question ,i was just suggesting an option.

Comment: ya but if number of book increases then you may to memory leaks. suppose you have 1000 book then?

Comment: could you just show me a link of tutorial on an example of this, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can store that values in 2 ways

1. Use Sqlite but some what coding is heavy for this.
2. Use serialization and deserialization to store data.